# Clean URL with PHP on XAMPP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been struggling for months now, and I'm just not getting it. I'm trying to get clean urls with php on xampp, I either get server error 500 or `www.something.com/root/index.php?page=whatever` does not go away I want `www.someting.com/page/queryresult/`

Can anyone help?

I think the problem is linking the menu to the query and the sticky part is in the switch

```
function display_menus_new()
{
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM menus";
 $query = mysql_query($sql) or  die(mysql_error());
 $array = array();
 if (mysql_num_rows($query)){
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$array[$rows['parent_id']][] = $rows;
}
loop_array($array); 
}
}
  function loop_array($array = array(), $parent_id = 0)
{
  if(!empty($array[$parent_id])) {
     echo '<ul>';
      foreach($array[$parent_id] as $items){
     echo '<li>';

 switch($items['name']){ 

case 'Home': print_r('<a href="home.php" >'.($items['name']).'</a>');   
        $items = str_replace("name", "", "");
case 'About': print_r('<a href="about.php" >'.($items['name']).'</a>'); 
         $items = str_replace("name", "", "");      

 case 'Services': print_r('<a href="services.php" >'.($items['name']).'</a>');  
        $items = str_replace("name", "", "");

  case 'Contact': print_r('<a href="contact.php" >'.($items['name']).'</a>');   
        $items = str_replace("name", "", ""); }
```

//This part Connects the menu to the Database Query Where ?Page= the Data Value connection

```
         print_r('<a href="?Page='.($items['name']).'" >'); 
    echo  $items['name'];
    loop_array($array, $items['Cat']);
echo '</a></li>';

        }
    echo '</ul>';


    }

 }
```

Comment: you can create your links as you like from your code, then you must implement a .htaccess rewriting of these links. so if your server gets a request for `example.com/page/2` it will translate it to `example.com?page=2` so your script can work. this is just an example ofc. a simple google search gives me this [link](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: Without your `htaccess` file and the `PHP` code we also "don't know where its going wrong".

Comment: I have Tried Variuos .httaccess rewriterules... still nothing works I don'nt know but maybe from the menu to the sql linking something is wrong, If I change print_r('<a href="/SiteDirectory/Page/'.($items['name']).'" >'); 
      
   echo  $items['name'];

Comment: is there no way I can e-mail someone the problem page and the .htaccsess, cause i thing it is between the menu and the query string that is not being changed in the url?

Comment: I'm Beginning to think that on the Switch function maybe its not right.. I think the problem is here somewhere .... because if I change the ?Page= to /Page/ i get Clean URL but the Data not found will paste example below of code

Comment: function display_menus_new()
{
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM menus";
 $query = mysql_query($sql) or  die(mysql_error());
 $array = array();
 if (mysql_num_rows($query)){
 while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $array[$rows['parent_id']][] = $rows;
}
 loop_array($array); 
}
}

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing such a convoluted attempt at clean URLs within PHP.  did you try the .htaccess approach?

Comment: Hi Dave, Most Tutorials are about crating single page links. I have Tried The httaccess routes and it does not work for some reason, I'm trying to link my sql menu with my database and get clean urls, I don't know any better, there must be a tutorial somewhere or somebody knows, out there I don't and was hoping someone knows a better way. So in a nutshell I need menu sql and a Products Database to display clean urls, because whatever I try even with .httaccess stil shows: www.site.com/?Result=Product1034 I managed to get rid of showing the index.php?Result=Product but not getting further..

Comment: I found the Problem.... My XAMPP Site was not set to Virtual Host, on localhost, thats whymy clean urls did not display, thanks for all the input

Answer (score 0):

add a file called `.htaccess` in your home directory

start the rewrite engine at the top of the file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
```

In that file, you'll write some conditions for re-directing to a clean URL:

```
#first, we need to define the request, in this case, index.php?page=whatever
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php?page=([0-9]*)
# now we need to make it look like it's just the clean url
RewriteRule ^$ /page/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+) /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This is a bit confusing, but basically what it means is that when your browser receives the ugly URL, it gets redirected to the pretty URL.  Then, the re-write fills the pretty URL with the content from the ugly URL.

Close your if statement after you're done re-writing:

```
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is the "easy", hacky way to do this.  The grown-up way is to use a router

Answer (score 0):

i have xampp on windows;

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Run everything else but real files through parse.php
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/dev-boards
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/tests
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(admin|admintemplate)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|png|html|js|json|jpg|jpeg)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ parse.php?info=$1 [L]
```

parse.php:

```
<?php

include("../connect.local.php");
session_start();
$getVars = $_GET['info'];

$vars = explode("/",$getVars);

//http://localhost/viewprofile/0/yes

//$vars[0] is "viewprofile"
//$vars[1] is 0
//$vars[2] is "yes"
```

What i do is i use file_exists to use $vars[0] and $vars[1] to reference a folder/file. if the file doesnt exist, route to $vars[0]/index.php

if the folder doesnt exists, redirect to index.php

Hope this helps to get you started.